# How To Access logs of the HTTP Requests in IIS or Query logs sent from Entity Framework to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, iis-8

I created a simple website with a login page that requires to authenticate only with an email address.

I did not store any login logs nor I enabled any logging functionalities on IIS.

Now, people are asking for the list of emails who logged in the past two days.

I used EntityFramework to connect to the database. This is the authentication method:

```
public static bool Authenticate(string email)
{            
    using (var db = new DatabaseEntities())
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user != null)
            return true;             
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have tired this in SQL but nothing relevant will show:

```
SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
```

Is there a way to access the logs in SQL for every time this line of code was executed?

```
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Perhaps there is a way to access the logs for every post request sent to the IIS server?

Comment: You can see logins for every connection in the standard SQL logs (obviously depends on authentication method). But it will not show queries. For that you need a trace or an Extended Events log.

Comment: I did not configure Extend Event Log.

Comment: Then there is nothing to see. The only thing you can see in the SQL logs is who is the actual SQL User on connection. That depends on how IIS is authenticating to SQL Server. [IIS does have logs though](https://stackify.com/where-are-iis-log-files-located/)

Comment: That is not what I need. Thank you for replying and trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't already enable a logging feature in IIS or SQL Server then there is nothing you can do retroactively unfortunately.

Moving forward you can pretty easily enable out of the box features of SQL Server to log User connections via either [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) or a [Logon Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) to store the log to a table.

[This article](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/auditing-select-statements-on-sql-server/) lists a few other methodologies (in addition to what I mentioned above) such as using a Trace.

Comment: Yup, I did not enable server side logging. Moving forward I will make sure to set up my own logging. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Victor_Tlepshev No problem, if you have any questions feel free. Also feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer so other users with similar questions see it verified as helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the queries sent by the application to the database cannot be viewed in IIS. These query records can only be viewed through SQL Server.

The Logging module in IIS records the communication between the client and the server, which includes the URL status code and time.

Even the Fail Request Tracing module cannot capture SQL Server query records, but only the communication records with SQL Server, such as request response time and success and failure.

Comment: Got you.. well I just got to do a better job next time. Thank you!